# YouTube API not retrieving playlist items uploaded with YT Music

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have just created a YouTube Music playlist and added to this playlist a song I have uploaded myself to YouTube Music.
Now, I'm using the YouTube API, sign in with the exact same user to have the correct oAuth token.
I'm able to see this playlist (with good counts of elements inside) when I retrieve the playlists list for my user.

But when I try to retrieve items in this playlist, all I can see is my video with a title "Private video" and a description "This video is private". So yes, it's a private video as I have uploaded it myself, but should at least get information correctly ! Like the title of the video / song I have uploaded previously.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

EDIT:
Yes, I'm using the PlaylistItems.list API endpoint queried with mine=true.
And here is the response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [kind] => youtube#playlistItemListResponse
    [etag] => sAQNugs9wcKG_EI3f71MecqShMo
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#playlistItem
                    [etag] => vL-NtUyJLqmlHMnPNX-ldbXRzhs
                    [id] => UExGU1NIZU5WbWZUQUQyTDc0VlJxUm5meGZwN3dNZTJ2by41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2
                    [snippet] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2020-08-14T08:55:20Z
                            [channelId] => XXXXX
                            [title] => Private video
                            [description] => This video is private.
                            [thumbnails] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                            [channelTitle] => XXXXX
                            [playlistId] => XXXXX
                            [position] => 0
                            [resourceId] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [kind] => youtube#video
                                    [videoId] => XXXXX
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [pageInfo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [totalResults] => 1
            [resultsPerPage] => 50
        )

)
```

So as you can see, no information about the video. But it's a song I have uploaded myself with the YouTube Music upload button.
And yes, I'm using the exact same user, so the access token is right.

And this same playlist if I open it on music.youtube.com is showing the song, while opening on youtube.com is not showing anything (even if connected with same user / profile)...

Steps to reproduce are quite easy:

- Go to music.youtube.com
- Upload a song from your device
- Add this song to a playlist
- Try to retrieve playlist items of this playlist with YouTube API V3...

Thank you !

Comment: What does it mean *I'm able to see this playlist [...] when I retrieve the playlists list for my user*? Are you using the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint queried with `mine=true`? If you indeed pass to this API endpoint the *correct* access token, then the API response will (have to) contain all info, including private data. On the other hand, do post a [*minimal reproducible sample code*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for to clearly see (and eventually test) your issue.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: this is not an actual answer, but more like a conjecture w.r.t. OP's issue.)

I can confirm uploading a (public, free of copyright issues) MP3 to my channel (which I do not disclose here) and observing the same results as OP's.

Here is what I obtained by way of a simple query to [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint (the ellipsis points below are anonymizing certain info):

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "...",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "...",
            "id": "...",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2020-08-15T14:11:45Z",
                "channelId": "...",
                "title": "Private video",
                "description": "This video is private.",
                "thumbnails": {
                },
                "channelTitle": "...",
                "playlistId": "...",
                "position": 0,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": "..."
                }
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "..."
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 50
    }
}
```

I do conjecture that this has to do with the fact that the API records the newly created playlist item as being *private* (do remark that `privacyStatus` is `private`) even in the case when that item and the playlist itself are *public* (as mine were).

In my opinion, the exhibited behavior is really a bug of the API.

Let's [wait and see](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164162564) what Google's support has to say about this.